# get row data in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have created a datatable in which, a dropdown is used, along with a button. All the data is coming from 'model.Cards' except for the dropdown in which the data is coming from 'model.Status'. After selecting status, when i click on button, how i will be able to get the data for that particular row, along with status? Id of all the dropdown's are same.

```
{ "mData": function(){
       return getStatusList();
    }, "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
       var returnValue="<select name='onlineUserStatus'>";
       var listItems= "";
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           listItems+= "<option value='" + data[i].Value + "'>" + data[i].Text + "</option>";
       }
       y--;
       return returnValue.concat(listItems,"</select>");
    },  "sWidth": "15%"},
    { "mData": null,
      "sClass": "center",
      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
         return '<input type="submit" Value="Block"' + '"/>';
    }
}
```

Above is the code, which renders the dropdown as well as button.

Answer (score 0):

Where table identifier & button identifier would be the html class or id names.

```
  $(table identifier).on('click', button identifier, function(e){

        e.stopPropagation();                

        var status = $(this).closest('tr').attr('status');

  });
```

That would get you value of status assuming it's in the tag like:

```
         <tr ... status="1">...</tr>
```

You could also modify it by using .find() by giving each column a class and searching through like that.